# Change style of stored div ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I'm trying to change some styling properties based on the div ID that I've been able to capture in a javascript function.

When the user selects a div, the javascript captures its ID. When they select the red button, whichever div is selected, it's background colour should be changed to red.

I've tried multiple ways and none of the approaches I've taken so far work.

Any ideas? Would greatly appreciate any and all suggestions!

```js
var sid;

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
  sid = clicked_id;
  console.log("Got ID!" + sid);
}

function btnRed() {
  console.log("Changed color for " + sid);
  sid.setProperty("background-color", "#ff4f4f");
}
```

```css
body {
  maring: 0;
  poadding: 0;
}

#colorPreview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#colorPreview2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-hillbilly.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="colorPreview" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
  <div id="colorPreview2" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>

  <button class="bttn-1" onclick="btnRed()">Red</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: instead of  `sid.setProperty` use `document.getElementById(sid).style.backgroundColor = "#ff4f4f";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but you have a few issues with your code. First of all, you need the element itself in order to change its properties; not its ID. `this.id` should be changed to simply `this`. And secondly, you need to change `sid.setProperty()` to `sid.style.setProperty()`.

Here's your code with the above fixes:

```js
var sid;

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
  sid = clicked_id;
  console.log("Got ID!" + sid);
}

function btnRed() {
  console.log("Changed color for " + sid);
  sid.style.setProperty("background-color", "#ff4f4f");
}
```

```css
body {
  maring: 0;
  poadding: 0;
}

#colorPreview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#colorPreview2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-hillbilly.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="colorPreview" onclick="reply_click(this)"></div>
  <div id="colorPreview2" onclick="reply_click(this)"></div>

  <button class="bttn-1" onclick="btnRed()">Red</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`sid` is an id, it's just a string, not a function so you can't call sid.now it's id of element and we can find the element with `document.getElementById()`. and also it's a good practice to check is any div selected or not.

```js
var sid;

function reply_click(clicked_id) {
  sid = clicked_id;
  console.log("Got ID!" + sid);
}

function btnRed() {
  console.log("Changed color for " + sid);
  //sid.setProperty("background-color", "#ff4f4f");
var doc = document.getElementById(sid)
if(doc){
doc.style.backgroundColor ="#ff4f4f"
}

}
```

```css
body {
  maring: 0;
  poadding: 0;
}

#colorPreview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#colorPreview2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-hillbilly.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="colorPreview" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>
  <div id="colorPreview2" onclick="reply_click(this.id)"></div>

  <button class="bttn-1" onclick="btnRed()">Red</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's working code. You can't use the id of an element to change the element. You need to get the element with the Id. So use ***this*** instead of ***this.id***.

```js
var selectedElem;

function reply_click(clickedElem) {
  selectedElem = clickedElem;
  console.log("Got ID!" + selectedElem.id);
}

function btnRed() {
  console.log("Changed color for " + selectedElem.id);
  selectedElem.style.setProperty("background-color", "#ff4f4f");
}
```

```css
body {
  maring: 0;
  poadding: 0;
}

#colorPreview {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#colorPreview2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-hillbilly.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="colorPreview" onclick="reply_click(this)"></div>
  <div id="colorPreview2" onclick="reply_click(this)"></div>

  <button class="bttn-1" onclick="btnRed()">Red</button>
</body>

</html>
```